# Why doesn't Py2App work but the package content exe does

Tags: python, macos, python-3.8, py2app

I have created a script using Python 3.8 that I am looking to turn into an app using Py2App. I have created the Alias mode app. However, the app does not work. Clicking it brings an error with the options "Open Console" and "Terminate". However, if I go into the package contents and click the .exe, that exe works. Why doesn't the main app work, but the inside exe does?

Using Python 3.8 on a MacBook.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not contain enough information to be able to tell what's wrong.

A good way to debug what's wrong is to start the application from the command-line. If your app bundle is named "Hello.app" you can start the app as "dist/Hello.app/Contents/MacOS/Hello" in the Terminal (in the same directory where you called py2app).

Usually this shows an error message in the Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact same issue.  Removing `"argv_emulation": True` from the OPTIONS object in the setup.py was the solution for me.

```
from setuptools import setup

OPTIONS = {
    'iconfile': 'icon.png'
   }

setup(
    app=['main.py'],
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=["py2app"]
}
```